# there is some mistake in this sql query

Tags: sql-server-2005

I wrote the following query, but it appears to have an error, and I was wondering if anyone could help me find it? I'm sorry about how long it is.

```
declare @Age int 
declare @Sex varchar(20)

set @Age=20
set @Sex='M'

select
    d.Dep_Name,d.Dep_Code,g.Group_Name,t.Test_Name,t.Test_Unit,(
    case 
        when at1.First_Age>=@Age and @Sex='M' then convert(varchar(10),at1.L_Bound_M_LessThan_1yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),at1.U_Bound_M_LessThan_1yr)
        when (at1.First_Age<@Age and at1.Second_Age>=@Age) and @Sex='M' then convert(varchar(10),at1.L_Bound_M_LessThan_20yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),at1.U_Bound_M_LessThan_20yr) 
        -- 5 more when statements

    ),
    st.Sub_Test_Name, st.Sub_Test_Unit, p.Result_Type, 
    p.Numeric_Value, p.Paragraph_Value ,p.Result_Normal,p.Sub_Test_ID,
    (
    case 
        when ast.First_Age>=@Age and @Sex='M' then convert(varchar(10),ast.L_Bound_M_LessThan_1yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),ast.U_Bound_M_LessThan_1yr) 
        --more WHEN's - mirrors the above case
    )
FROM 
    Patient_Test_3SC p LEFT JOIN
    ((Tests t INNER JOIN 
      Advanced_test_detail at1 on t.test_id=at1.test_id) LEFT JOIN 
     (Sub_Tests st INNER JOIN 
      Advanced_Sub_tests ast on st.sub_test_id=ast.sub_test_id) on t.Test_Code=st.Sub_Tests_Test_Code) 
         ON p.Test_ID=t.Test_ID 
    INNER JOIN Department d on p.Department_Code=d.Dep_Code 
    LEFT JOIN Groups g on p.Group_Code=g.Group_Code 
WHERE p.Patient_ID=@pid
```

I've had some errors in the code, and I'm not entirely sure where they're from. Could someone please assist me in figuring out why I have an error in this SQL code?

Comment: Couldn't it possible to simplify it a little bit? or at least let us know what should this query do?! or it's an IQ test?!!

Comment: Okay, in all seriousness, that's a massive amount of SQL. Could you please tell us what errors you're getting with this code? It'll make everyone's job easier if you can at least assist us in assisting you.

Comment: at least we know it should run on sql server 2005..!

Comment: @Afshin: Yes, you're right. I just think that providing the error would be helpful for anyone to assist in debugging the problem, and perhaps helping the asker to learn what might be problematic with his/her code. Obviously, though, I'd assume that I'm preaching to the converted and you're a more extensive user than I am anyway ^^ But still, an idea of what the SQL Server 2005 thinks is wrong would be helpful ^^

Comment: sorry for trobbleing you,in this sql i join 6 tables and there is two tables Advanced_test_detail and Advance_Sub_test whose colums are selected by using case statement

Comment: @afsin=it gives Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @user1023160 which line is line 18?

Comment: Also you need to add an `END` to the case statements `CASE WHEN x THEN x END`

Comment: His parens /appear/ to be balanced, but god only knows what's really going on there.

Comment: Prescott probably has the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @Age int 
declare @Sex varchar(20)
declare @pid varchar(20)

set @Age=20
set @Sex='M'

SELECT
    d.Dep_Name,d.Dep_Code,g.Group_Name,t.Test_Name,t.Test_Unit,
    st.Sub_Test_Name, st.Sub_Test_Unit, p.Result_Type, 
    p.Numeric_Value, p.Paragraph_Value ,p.Result_Normal,p.Sub_Test_ID,
    CASE 
        when at1.First_Age>=@Age and @Sex='M' then convert(varchar(10),at1.L_Bound_M_LessThan_1yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),at1.U_Bound_M_LessThan_1yr)
        when (at1.First_Age<@Age and at1.Second_Age>=@Age) and @Sex='M' then convert(varchar(10),at1.L_Bound_M_LessThan_20yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),at1.U_Bound_M_LessThan_20yr) 
        -- 5 more when statements
    END as 'var1',
    CASE 
        when ast.First_Age>=@Age and @Sex='M' then convert(varchar(10),ast.L_Bound_M_LessThan_1yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),ast.U_Bound_M_LessThan_1yr) 
        --more WHEN's - mirrors the above case
    END as 'var2'
FROM 
    Patient_Test_3SC p LEFT JOIN
    ((Tests t INNER JOIN Advanced_test_detail at1 on t.test_id=at1.test_id) LEFT JOIN 
     (Sub_Tests st INNER JOIN Advanced_Sub_tests ast on st.sub_test_id=ast.sub_test_id) on t.Test_Code=st.Sub_Tests_Test_Code) 
    ON p.Test_ID=t.Test_ID 
    INNER JOIN Department d on p.Department_Code=d.Dep_Code 
    LEFT JOIN Groups g on p.Group_Code=g.Group_Code 
WHERE p.Patient_ID=@pid
```

Comment: maybe - I'm not 100% but it seems to pass muster

Answer (score 3):

Just corrected syntax errors, and we will not discuss about how weird the query is.

```
declare @Age int 
set @Age=20

declare @Sex varchar(20)
set @Sex='M'

select
d.Dep_Name,d.Dep_Code,g.Group_Name,t.Test_Name,t.Test_Unit,
case 
when at1.First_Age>=@Age and @Sex='M' then convert(varchar(10),at1.L_Bound_M_LessThan_1yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),at1.U_Bound_M_LessThan_1yr)
when (at1.First_Age<@Age and at1.Second_Age>=@Age) and @Sex='M' then convert(varchar(10),at1.L_Bound_M_LessThan_20yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),at1.U_Bound_M_LessThan_20yr) 
when (at1.Second_Age<@Age and at1.Third_Age>=@Age) and @Sex='M' then convert(varchar(10),at1.L_Bound_M_LessThan_40yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),at1.U_Bound_M_LessThan_40yr)
when (at1.Third_Age<@Age and at1.Fourth_Age>=@Age) and @Sex='M' then convert(varchar(10),at1.L_Bound_M_LessThan_60yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),at1.U_Bound_M_LessThan_60yr) 
when (at1.Fourth_Age<@Age and at1.Fifth_Age>=@Age) and @Sex='M' then convert(varchar(10),at1.L_Bound_M_LessThan_125yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),at1.U_Bound_M_LessThan_125yr) 
when at1.First_Age>=@Age and @Sex='F' then convert(varchar(10),at1.L_Bound_F_LessThan_1yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),at1.U_Bound_F_LessThan_1yr) 
when (at1.First_Age<@Age and at1.Second_Age>=@Age) and @Sex='F' then convert(varchar(10),at1.L_Bound_F_LessThan_20yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),at1.U_Bound_F_LessThan_20yr) 
when (at1.Second_Age<@Age and at1.Third_Age>=@Age) and @Sex='F' then convert(varchar(10),at1.L_Bound_F_LessThan_40yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),at1.U_Bound_F_LessThan_40yr) 
when (at1.Third_Age<@Age and at1.Fourth_Age>=@Age) and @Sex='F' then convert(varchar(10),at1.L_Bound_F_LessThan_60yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),at1.U_Bound_F_LessThan_60yr) 
when (at1.Fourth_Age<@Age and at1.Fifth_Age>=@Age) and @Sex='F' then convert(varchar(10),at1.L_Bound_F_LessThan_60yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),at1.U_Bound_F_LessThan_60yr)
ELSE NULL END AS x ,
st.Sub_Test_Name,st.Sub_Test_Unit,p.Result_Type,p.Numeric_Value,p.Paragraph_Value,p.Result_Normal,p.Sub_Test_ID,
case 
when ast.First_Age>=@Age and @Sex='M' then convert(varchar(10),ast.L_Bound_M_LessThan_1yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),ast.U_Bound_M_LessThan_1yr) 
when (ast.First_Age<@Age and ast.Second_Age>=@Age) and @Sex='M' then convert(varchar(10),ast.L_Bound_M_LessThan_20yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),ast.U_Bound_M_LessThan_20yr) 
when (ast.Second_Age<@Age and ast.Third_Age>=@Age) and @Sex='M' then convert(varchar(10),ast.L_Bound_M_LessThan_40yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),ast.U_Bound_M_LessThan_40yr) 
when (ast.Third_Age<@Age and ast.Fourth_Age>=@Age) and @Sex='M' then convert(varchar(10),ast.L_Bound_M_LessThan_60yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),ast.U_Bound_M_LessThan_60yr) 
when (ast.Fourth_Age<@Age and ast.Fifth_Age>=@Age) and @Sex='M' then convert(varchar(10),ast.L_Bound_M_LessThan_125yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),ast.U_Bound_M_LessThan_125yr) 
when ast.First_Age>=@Age and @Sex='F' then convert(varchar(10),ast.L_Bound_F_LessThan_1yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),ast.U_Bound_F_LessThan_1yr) 
when (ast.First_Age<@Age and ast.Second_Age>=@Age) and @Sex='F' then convert(varchar(10),ast.L_Bound_F_LessThan_20yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),ast.U_Bound_F_LessThan_20yr) 
when (ast.Second_Age<@Age and ast.Third_Age>=@Age) and @Sex='F' then convert(varchar(10),ast.L_Bound_F_LessThan_40yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),ast.U_Bound_F_LessThan_40yr) 
when (ast.Third_Age<@Age and ast.Fourth_Age>=@Age) and @Sex='F' then convert(varchar(10),ast.L_Bound_F_LessThan_60yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),ast.U_Bound_F_LessThan_60yr) 
when (ast.Fourth_Age<@Age and ast.Fifth_Age>=@Age) and @Sex='F' then convert(varchar(10),ast.L_Bound_F_LessThan_60yr)+'-'+convert(varchar(10),ast.U_Bound_F_LessThan_60yr) 
ELSE NULL END AS y

from Patient_Test_3SC p 
left join((Tests t inner join Advanced_test_detail at1 on t.test_id=at1.test_id ) 
left join (Sub_Tests st inner join Advanced_Sub_tests ast on st.sub_test_id=ast.sub_test_id) on t.Test_Code=st.Sub_Tests_Test_Code) on p.Test_ID=t.Test_ID 
inner join Department d on p.Department_Code=d.Dep_Code 
left join Groups g on p.Group_Code=g.Group_Code 
where p.Patient_ID=@pid
```

Answer (score 0):

from Patient_Test_3SC p

maybe it need have a ',' between table Patient_test_3SC and p

Comment: ok it is solved there is two mistake in that sql 1st is that i forget to write end(it is suggested by prescott,thanks for his kind help) and second one it didn't give the column alias at the end of case